# Is it the Whitehaven Boy's Soccer Booster Club

Tags: grammatical-number

Or is it the Whitehaven Boys' Soccer Booster Club?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate; I'll see if I can dig up the canonical question. The short answer is "*boys'*", with the apostrophe after the `s`, because there is more than one Whitehaven Boy.

Comment: If you're in Memphis, Tennesssee it's "Boys'"; anywhere else, you'll have to consult the Club charter.  It's a proper name and they get to call themselves whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Whitehaven Boys' Soccer Booster Club. You can see [here](http://www.scsk12.org/schools/whitehaven.hs/site/Soccer.shtml) that Mr. Huber is the *boys'* head coach, not the *boy's* head coach — unless, of course, this is a Soccer Booster Club named for ol' Pete Whitehaven's boy, Dickie, in which case it is (that rascally) Whitehaven Boy's Soccer Booster Club.